# same iPhone and iPad project, css not working properly in iPad

Tags: css, iphone, html, ipad, cordova

I'm using phone gap and query mobile. With the same code for iPhone and iPad project, css is not working properly in iPad.
how can be possible that on the iPhone the link is not broken and on the iPad isn't?

Here's my link code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/test.css" />
```

Path for css files:

```
js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css
js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/test.css
```

Path for image files:

```
js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

Before beating yourself up, try clearing the cache on the iPhone, you might find out the link was already broken.

Comment: I've cleaned my project and rebuilt but nothing new

Comment: I've noticed that only a small part of the css code is not recognised: the images under the images folder, on the iPhone are working well cleaning everything.